# Add name of directory as file name extension

Tags: bash, find, file-rename

Have multiple directories containing similar filenames inside. I want to rename the files and append name of directory as extension to filename. Here is an example:

```
dir1
    file1
    file2
    file3

dir2 
    file1
    file2
    file3
```

What I am doing at the moment is running the following inside each directory to bulk rename.

```
$> cd dir1
$> for f in *; do mv "$f" "$f.dir1"; done
$> ls 
$> file1.dir1    file2.dir1    file3.dir1  
$> cd ../dir2
$> for f in *; do mv "$f" "$f.dir2"; done
$> ls 
$> file1.dir2    file2.dir2    file3.dir2
```

But this becomes redundant and I am wondering if there a way to automate and do this for both dir1 and dir2 at once being from a parent dir to both. A somewhat related question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987846/how-to-bulk-add-folder-name-to-file-name); but it might take me sometime to understand and port it to my platform as I hardly write ms window scripts.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your script like that  :

```
for d in *; do
if [ -d $d ] ; then
    cd $d; 
    for f in *; do  
        mv "$f" "$f.$d"; 
    done 
    cd ..; 
fi
done
```

From the parent directory , you can execute it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this from the parent directory:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'dir*' -exec bash -c \
'for file in "${1}"/* ; do
     echo -v "${file}" "${file}"."$(basename "${1}")"
 done' -- {} \;
```

Replace `echo` by `mv` if it works for you.